# How can I fix a partition conflict?

Tags: ubuntu, partition, dual-boot

I am running Ubuntu 10.10 on a 250 gb hdd. I chose at installation to install all on one partition (it was recommended for beginners). Unfortunately, I need to use Windows 7 too. I didn't want to format the drive to install Windows first and Ubuntu after, so I used `gparted` to resize the 250 gb partition, and made a 65 gb NTFS primary. I installed Windows 7, but upon restart it boots automatically to Windows 7; I can't see Ubuntu. I did try to press shift many times to bring up GRUB, but it did nothing. What can I do in this situation?

Answer (score 8):

When you installed Windows it replaced GRUB with the Windows bootloader, which doesn't recognize Linux. You need to boot off the Ubuntu live CD again and reinstall GRUB. The gist of the command is:

```
# grub-install /dev/sda
```

where `sda` is the drive you're booting off of. There's a good guide on [help.ubuntu.com](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/RecoveringUbuntuAfterInstallingWindows) that explains exactly what `grub-install` you should run, based on your setup